# Convex hull in different coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-systems, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Given a set of points $X \subset R^n$, points are the row of $X$. We can find it's Convex hull $CH(X)$. And assuming the $X$ here are in cartesian coordinate.

There are many other coordinate systems, e.g. Polar coordinate system, homogeneous coordinate system.

And we can convert $X$ into Polar coordinates to obtain $Y := polar(CH(X))$. In this new coordinate system, What's the relationship between $CH(Y)$ and $CH(X)$ ?

Comment: Convexity is a property of a set and is independent of coordinate systems. The unit ball for instance is convex, whether one uses cartession or spherical coordinates to represent it. However, if a set $A$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ is a homeomorphism, $h(A)$ is not necessarily convex  in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Is this the source of your confusion?

Comment: thanks, I have changed the question a little bit, $Y =polar(CH(X))$, since I'm interested in the convex hull here. And a $T: R^n -> R\times[0, 1]^{n-1}$, cartesian to polar transformation, would change the extreme points on CH.